# Why does Vim highlight Javadoc comments like this?

Tags: java, vim, syntax-highlighting

I am using `vim` to edit Java code. I added a Javadoc header above the class definition, but the syntax highlighting is very strange:

[image]
*read the Javadoc comment above*

Why is the first sentence highlighted white while the rest is highlighted gray?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The reason for the special highlighting of the first sentence is to emphasize that it is the summary of the Javadoc comment. The first sentence of a Javadoc comment is handled specially by the Javadoc tool, see [this description](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/documentation/index-137868.html#descriptions) of how Javadoc comments are interpreted.